# How do I move 301 redirects from IIS 6 to IIS 7?

Tags: iis-7, iis-6

I'm moving a site from Windows Server 2003/ IIS6 to Windows Server 2008 R2/ IIS7. Assuming it can be done, how do I move the `301` redirects from the IIS 6 installation to the new IIS 7 installation? (I'm surprised that I was not able to find an answer to this question either here or with Google.)

**Edit:** Or asked another way, what do large sites do about existing `301` redirects when migrating from IIS 6 to IIS 7? I only have a little over 100 redirects to migrate, but I don't want to manually reenter them into IIS 7, that's for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overkill IMO, but it works. Use the Microsoft utility, MS Deploy.

Here are some instructions and a download link:

[IIS6 to IIS7 Migration](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1614-iis6-to-iis7-migration)

The tool will migrate an entire site. It's not clear from the examples given, but it is possible to migrate the 301 redirects only using the optional GUI.